# Why 'api' is not defined? (beginner)

Tags: python, api, twitter, nameerror

I think i defined 'api' as twitter.api, idk why this error is happening
code:

```
 import twitter


def auth():                      
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='CsqkkrnhBZQMhGLpnkqGqOUOV',
    consumer_secret='jzbWgRLZqIyJQjfh572LgbtuifBtXw6jwm1V94oqcQCzJd7VAE',
    access_token_key='1300635453247361031-EWTTGf1B6T2GUqWmFwzLfvgni3PoVH',
    access_token_secret='U2GZsWT0TvL5U24BG9X4NDAb84t1BB059qdoyJgGqhWN4')
                                
auth()
api.PostUpdate('Hello World')
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Xtrike/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/twitter python.py", line 11, in <module>
    api.PostUpdate('Hello World')
NameError: name 'api' is not defined
```

Comment: You defined `api` in function `auth()`, then tried to reach it in `global` context.

Comment: Either move `api.PostUpdate('Hello World')` into function or init `api` in global context: `api = None` before actual usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to learn about [local and global scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) in Python. In short you've created a local variable `api` that is not visible outside of function.

As of solving the provided error, there are different approaches depending on desired result:

1. Use reserved word `global` to make variable visible at global scope:

```
def auth():
    global api # This does the trick publishing variable in global scope
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='<>',
        consumer_secret='<>',
        access_token_key='<>',
        access_token_secret='<>')
                                
auth()
api.PostUpdate('Hello World') # api variable actually published at global scope
```

However I'd not recommend using global variables without proper conscise

2. Provided code is small so no need to wrap into additional function

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='<>',
        consumer_secret='<>',
        access_token_key='<>',
        access_token_secret='<>')
                                
api.PostUpdate('Hello World')
```

3. Returning object from function - I recommend this approach as most suitable and reliable

```
def auth():                      
    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='<>',
        consumer_secret='<>',
        access_token_key='<>',
        access_token_secret='<>')
    return api
                                
api = auth()
api.PostUpdate('Hello World')
```

Last, but important word: avoid publishing secrets in public posts - these are not needed for solution but may be exposed to wrecker.

Comment: tysm!! about the secret, it's not that important, it's just a test account. Have a good day and stay healthy :)

Answer (score 0):

For what you posted, you need to initiate `api` variable. It just get everything and do the `PostUpdate`, but first you need to instantiate it.

Comment: Can you give an example pls?

Comment: `global api`, just that. (: